# A bi-modal logic related to determinacy

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, modal-logic, determinacy

The short version of my question is as follows. There is a natural (I hope!) way to associate a bimodal theory to a game *(two-player, perfect-information, length-$\omega$, on $\omega$)*; are there "natural" theories which completely pin down its possible behavior?

---

Let $K$ be the set of pairs $(\Sigma,\Pi)$ of quasistrategies for players $1$ and $2$ respectively. Endow $K$ with two accessibility relations $\rightarrow_1$ and $\rightarrow_2$ given by:

- $(\Sigma,\Pi)\rightarrow_1(\Sigma',\Pi')$ iff $\Sigma\supseteq \Sigma'$ and $\Pi=\Pi'$.
- $(\Sigma,\Pi)\rightarrow_2(\Sigma',\Pi')$ iff $\Sigma=\Sigma'$ and $\Pi\supseteq\Pi'$.

Basically, when we move along $\rightarrow_1$ (resp. $\rightarrow_2$) we're saying more about how player $1$ (resp. player $2$) is going to play.

Our bimodal language will be generated by the usual propositional connectives, modalities $\Box_1$ and $\Box_2$ *(and I'll write "$\Diamond_i$" for "$\neg\Box_i\neg$" per usual)*, and two propositional atoms ${\bf w}$ and ${\bf l}$.

To each $G\subseteq\omega^\omega$ we then assign a valuation $V_G:K\times\{{\bf w},{\bf l}\}\rightarrow\{\top,\perp\}$ *(and conflate this with its obvious extension to the whole language)* as follows:

- $V_G((\Sigma,\Pi), {\bf w})=\top$ iff every play in which players $1$ and $2$ play consistently with $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ respectively results in a win for player $1$.
- $V_G((\Sigma,\Pi), {\bf l})=\top$ iff every play in which players $1$ and $2$ play consistently with $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ respectively results in a win for player $2$.

Now here's the object I'm interested in:

> **Definition**. Let $\mathbb{G}$ be the set of all $\varphi$ in our modal language such that for every $G\subseteq\omega^\omega$ and every $(\Sigma,\Pi)\in K$ we have $V_G((\Sigma,\Pi),\varphi)=\top$.

My question is:

> **Question**. Is there a natural theory extending ZF which decides whether $\varphi\in\mathbb{T}$ for each $\varphi$ in our bimodal language?

For example, over ZF, AD proves (indeed is equivalent to) the $\mathbb{T}$-membership of $(\Diamond_1\Box_2{\bf w})\vee (\Diamond_2\Box_1{\bf l})$.

Comment: Very nice idea. I like it very much.

Comment: I've substantially revised this question; looking back at it, the original version was impossibly broad. Incidentally, the motivation for this question ultimately comes from thinking about notions of determinacy for three-person games. Determinacy itself clearly fails: consider the game in which player 1 decides which of players 2 and 3 wins. But in every three-person game I can cook up, at least one player can do **something**. While trying to figure out the right way to talk about this "something," I realized that even in the two-player setting there is a basic question which I can't answer.