# Bimodal determinacy logic for Borel games

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory, descriptive-set-theory, modal-logic

*This question is intended to be a first step towards answering [this old question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296195/a-bi-modal-logic-related-to-determinacy).*

---

Let $K$ be the set of pairs $(\Sigma,\Pi)$ of quasistrategies, in the usual sense of games on $\omega$, for players $1$ and $2$ respectively. Endow $K$ with two accessibility relations $\rightarrow_1$ and $\rightarrow_2$ given by:

- $(\Sigma,\Pi)\rightarrow_1(\Sigma',\Pi')$ iff $\Sigma\supseteq \Sigma'$ and $\Pi=\Pi'$.
- $(\Sigma,\Pi)\rightarrow_2(\Sigma',\Pi')$ iff $\Sigma=\Sigma'$ and $\Pi\supseteq\Pi'$.

Basically, when we move along $\rightarrow_1$ (resp. $\rightarrow_2$) we're saying more about how player $1$ (resp. player $2$) is going to play. I'm going to think of the triple $(K,\rightarrow_1,\rightarrow_2)$ as a "bimodal Kripke frame:" given a set $P$ of propositional atoms and an assigment $\nu:P\times K\rightarrow\{\top,\perp\}$, we get an obvious definition of "$\varphi$ is true at $(\Sigma,\Pi)$ according to $\nu$" for $\varphi$ a sentence in bimodal propositional logic with modalities $\Diamond_1,\Diamond_2$ *(= just "sentence" for short, below)* corresponding to $\rightarrow_1,\rightarrow_2$.

Now fix distinct propositional atoms ${\bf w},{\bf l}$ and let $P=\{\bf w\rm, \bf l\rm\}$. Each game (or rather, payoff set) $G\subseteq\omega^\omega$ has a corresponding valuation $\nu_G:P\times K\rightarrow\{\top,\perp\}$ given by:

- $\nu_G((\Sigma,\Pi),{\bf w})=\top$ iff $1$ wins every play with payoff set $G$ in which $1$ follows $\Sigma$ and $2$ follows $\Pi$.
- $\nu_G((\Sigma,\Pi),{\bf l})=\top$ iff $2$ wins every play with payoff set $G$ in which $1$ follows $\Sigma$ and $2$ follows $\Pi$.

**Finally**, conflating $\nu_G$ with its obvious extension to all sentences, let $\mathsf{BL}$ be the set of all sentences made true at every world by $\nu_G$ for every *Borel* $G\subseteq\omega^\omega$. Basically, $\mathsf{BL}$ is the set of all "determinacy-theoretic" principles true about every Borel game (in a very limited sense of course).

At a glance, I suspect that $\mathsf{BL}$ is actually rather simple, and indeed should really only have one nontrivial axiom, namely $\Diamond_1\Box_2{\bf w}\vee\Diamond_2\Box_1{\bf l}$ (= Borel determinacy). My question is, essentially, whether this could be right:

> Is $\mathsf{BL}$ decidable?

I don't see any immediate line of attack. My instinct is that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ should be "complete for simple questions about Borel games" (which would of course give a positive answer); however, I don't see how to prove that at all (and this is related to the fact that the above-linked question is still open).

Comment: Obvious but perhaps worth saying: determinacy can be expressed more simply as $\Diamond_1{\bf w}\vee\Diamond_2{\bf l}.$ Indeed ${\bf w}=\square_1\square_2{\bf w}.$ Also, ${\bf l}=\square_1\square_2\neg{\bf w},$ and determinacy of the misère game gives $\Diamond_1{\bf l}\vee\Diamond_2{\bf w}.$